# Chrome Dev Tools Issue With ES6 String Literals/Typescript

Tags: string, google-chrome, debugging, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a project using Typescript and some of the ES6 features exposed by Typescript like ES6 String Literals e.g. `` `Something ${variable} Something else` ``.

Whilst debugging a problem I dropped a breakpoint into my typescript file to step through it in the source panel, which usually works fine.

But Chrome Dev Tools has an issue with ES6 String literals and doesn't seem to recognise the end of an ES6 String literal.

Instead all code following the string literal is marked red (string highlighting in debugger) and blocked from variable inspection as chrome debugger seems to think it is all one massive string.

Has someone encountered this issue, found a fix or knows whether this is on Google's roadmap for Chrome Dev Tools?

**EDIT 1:**
Looks like this issue is currently being worked on by the Chromium team. See issue report for updates:
[bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659515](http://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659515)

**EDIT 2:**
Bug has been open for quite some time, but doesn't seem to have been prioritised. If you experience the issue go to the chromium link above and star/comment on it with helpful info to move it into focus of the Dev Tools team.

Comment: Did you manage this find anything? A bug report maybe? It's driving me nuts too.

Comment: @YesMan85 Found an open bug report - looks like they are still working on a fix: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659515

Comment: Ok thanks, I put in a bug too yesterday with a repo case, hope they can pick it up.

Comment: Anybody running into this issue should star the chromium bug / add more info and evidence. Hoping this gets picked up as its very annoying

Comment: In the link, you provided this issue is marked as "fixed" but actually it's still broken. Does anybody know if there is a new link to this issue which we could upvote to enforce this bug fixing?

Comment: @OlegPro: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=859872

Comment: Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 36):

As for version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) in Ubuntu is still a bug.

As a workaround you can start adding: `` //` `` to the end of lines containing templated strings, which fixes the formatting in the chrome sources tab.

Here some examples of my working jsx code.

---

In component props:

```
  <Field
    name={`${fields.name}[${index}].comments`}// `
    component="input"
    type="text"
  />
```

As a child element:

```
  <label>
    {`${t('Condone')}  `}{/* ` */}
  </label>
```

In a statement:

```
  switch (DEBTTYPE) {
    case DEBTTYPE_MACHINE_PRODUCT:
      id = `machine_product_difference_row_${row.id_productdebt}`;// `
      break;
      ....
```

I really hope that they can fix this issue as fast as possible.

Comment: Great stuff ! Thank you!!

Comment: @Rodrigo you are a hacker. Thank you. it worked

Answer (score 3):

This [December 14, 2017](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659515#c37) comment from the DevTools team says that they updated the CodeMirror version used in DevTools, and the issue should be fixed now. In Chrome 64 and beyond it should work. In earlier versions of Chrome it'll still be broken. You can check your version at `chrome://version`.

Comment: I just updated to Chrome 64 and can confirm that the bug is fixed

Comment: Still broken. Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Broken in Version 65.0.3325.162. I've starred the issue at https://crbug.com/659515

Comment: Broken in 68.0.3438.3. I've starred the issue at [crbug.com/659515](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659515)

Comment: Broken in Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: broken on Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Broken in Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: broken in version: Google Chrome 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Still broken 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit). Nobody cares

Comment: Still broken in Version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit).
Bug report stating it's been fixed.

Comment: Still broken in Version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (64-bit)
[the closed bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659515) says if anyone can provide reproductions with source (and sourcemaps) they'll take another look.

Comment: Still broken in Version 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) (64-bit). Current status, following the previous comment, someone provided the requested source and map files, but no official updates. The bug remains with status Fixed.

Answer (score -4):

If you are using Typescript, you can work around this issue by compiling your code to ES2015 and using source maps. This way, the backtick interpolated strings would be converted to the good ol' `"string " + variable + " string"`, but you would still be able to debug while looking at the original typescript code with backticks.

This would require adding the following to your tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2015",
        "sourceMap": true, 
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And if you serve locally the generated source map files (`.js.map`) alongside the generated `.js` files, you should be able to open the typescript files in chrome dev tools under "Sources" with `Ctrl-p`.

Comment: The issue is that the syntax highlighting does not work on TS source maps with backticks. Your method still ends up showing a TypeScript file with backticks in the Chrome debugger.

Comment: This is not a solution to OP's question, it is not even related to what he is asking.