# chrome devtools source not inspectable after backtick

Tags: javascript, debugging, breakpoints, inspect

If I stop my javascript code in a breakpoint and try to inspect certain part of the code like a variable or a function by hovering over, it gives a popup with its value like in the screenshot below:

[image]

But If I use es6 template strings in my code like this:

```
options.push(<option key={`traveller-age-option-${i}`}>{i}</option>);
```

Then the entire code below the backtick character (`) becomes red and if I hover over it - I'm not able to inspect any values - nothing happens - it is treated as a string

[image]

Because of this I have to manually go to console and type the value - not hover and see it's value.

How to fix this??
Is there a webpack option or some source-map or any chrome plugin which helps with this??

Comment: FYI that character is called a backtick, this (`~`) is a tilde.

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround using comments to test as explained in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864026/chrome-dev-tools-issue-with-es6-string-literals-typescript)

Seems to be a bug known by the Chromium team and they've been working on it for quite a while. [Issue here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=659515)

Hope that workaround makes your life a bit easy while debugging