# why source code highlighted in red in debugger chrome devtool

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, jsx

Why the code in the source section is all red when i use debugger?
More over i hover the variable but no information provided about it

see my pic:

[image: the code in the source section is all red in chrome devtool]

I work with react components for a long, but see such behaviour for the first time

Comment: Possibly an unrecognized token (by the dev tools) in the file, or that fact that it's JSX inside a JS file?

Comment: Probably a bug in devtools like https://crbug.com/875695, it doesn't recognize the end of a template string literal.

Comment: @EmileBergeron it doesnt worked perfectly till now with such files. That's not the first jsx file opened at devtool as js one

Comment: got the same bug after a string literal

Comment: may be this is what you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864026/chrome-dev-tools-issue-with-es6-string-literals-typescript